# Powershell Split string with "-" and digits and ".xml"

Tags: regex, powershell

```
$string = abc_test.txt-1234.xml  
$string2 = abc_test.txt-456789.xml  
$string3 = MFG-123 abc_dev.txt-11999.xml
```

trying to split so that I get the string before "-1234.xml" , anything before "-"and digits and ".xml".

```
$new = $string -Split'(?=-\d)'
$new[0]
```

this fails for string3 and returns "MFG" but i need "MFG-123 abc_dev.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use split, you could use your positive lookahead `(?=-\d)` to assert what is directly to the right is a `-` and a digits. T

Add a nested negative lookahead `(?!.*-\d)` to assert that there are no more of those matches following.

```
(?=-\d(?!.*-\d))
```

**Explanation**

- `(?=` Postive lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is

  - `-\d` Match `-` and a digit
  - `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

    - `.*-\d` Match any char except a newline 0+ times, then match `-` and a digit
  - `)` Close lookahead
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZPqMaP/1)

```
$string = 'abc_test.txt-1234.xml'
$string2 = 'abc_test.txt-456789.xml'
$string3 = 'MFG-123 abc_dev.txt-11999.xml'

$split = $string -Split'(?=-\d(?!.*-\d))'
echo $split[0] # abc_test.txt
echo $split[1] # -1234.xml

$split2 = $string2 -Split'(?=-\d(?!.*-\d))'
echo $split2[0] # abc_test.txt
echo $split2[1] # -456789.xml

$split3 = $string3 -Split'(?=-\d(?!.*-\d))'
echo $split3[0] # MFG-123 abc_dev.txt
echo $split3[1] #-11999.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
$string -replace '-\d+\.[^.]*$'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/slL3Z0/1)

**Details**

- `-`  - a hyphen
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `[^.]*`  - 0+ chars other than `.`
- `$` - end of string.

Test:

```
>>'abc_test.txt-1234.xml' -replace '-\d+\.[^.]*$'
abc_test.txt
>>'abc_test.txt-456789.xml' -replace '-\d+\.[^.]*$'
abc_test.txt
>>'MFG-123 abc_dev.txt-11999.xml'-replace '-\d+\.[^.]*$'
MFG-123 abc_dev.txt
```